# How do you check if a entered password contains 3 consecutive letters on the UK QWERTY keyboard in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords

If for example the password has 3 consecutive letter from the QWERTY keyboard, for every 3 in the password 5 point are deducted from the score. These 3 consecutive letters can be either upper or lower case and doesn't affect if it is in the same order.

For example if password was =

" t Y u " = - 5

" a s d F G " = - 15

Comment: Do you consider only letters, or do you also count punctuation or numbers? Do you count things across key row boundaries, e.g. does `pas` count because it's part of `qwertyuiopasdf...`, or do you only consider consecutives if they exist on the same row? Have you tried anything, and if so, what is that code?

Comment: *Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.* https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: if it is homework google is your friend: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177415/python-qwerty-keyboard-checker